# Converting a RGB image to grayscale based on the intensity of one color channel

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb, grayscale, hsv

I'm working with images similar to this: [a cell image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3PkF.jpg), and I want to extract only the red-pink sections. As of now I'm using `img(:,:,1)` to pull out the red values but this produces a binary image. I wanted to know if there was a way to extract the "red" values and produce a grayscale image based on their degree of "redness" or intensity. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: It shouldn't produce a binary image. Why do you think it's binary? Try `imagesc(img(:,:,1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely visualizing the result using `imshow` which will automatically set the color limits of the axes to be between `0` and `1`. Your image is RGB and the values of the red channel are going to range from `0` to `255`. Because of this, if you only specify one input to `imshow`, you will get an image where all values > `1` will appear as white and all zero-values will be black. So your image isn't really binary, it just *appears that way*.

You want to either display your image with `imagesc` which will automatically scale the color limits to match your data:

```
imagesc(img(:,:,1));
colormap gray
```

Or you can specify the second input to `imshow` to cause it to also scale to fit your data range:

```
imshow(img(:,:,1), [])
```

The reason that this isn't an issue when you are visualizing all channels is that if you specify red, green, and blue channels, this is considered a true color image and all axes color limits are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

The data you capture will be correct (and is grayscale), but the visualization may be incorrect. When trying to visualize a 2D matrix (same as your result `img(:,:,1)`), matlab applies the default colormap and the result is:

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:200, 1:200);
z=x.^2.*sin(y/max(y(:))*pi);
figure;imagesc(z);
```

[image]

If you want to avoid the applied `jet` colormap, either change the colormap:

```
colormap('gray')
```

[image]

or change your 2D matrix into a 3D one, explicitely specifying the colors to display (must be values between 0 and 1):

```
z3d = z(:,:,[1 1 1]); % more efficient than repmat
z3d = (z3d - min(z(:)))./range(z(:)); % make sure values in range [0; 1]
```

[image]

You see banding in the colormap version, because by default a colormap [contains 64 different colors](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html); the 3d matrix version doesn't have this problem as it directly displays the colors.

Answer (score 2):

If I may add to your question, it seems to me you're simply trying to isolate and visualise the red, green, and blue fluorofores separately (or in combination). I specifically think this because you mention 'pink'.

It may be nicer to just isolate the channels:

```
>> F_red = F; F_red(:,:,[2,3]) = 0;
>> F_green = F; F_green(:,:,[1,3]) = 0;
>> F_blue = F; F_blue(:,:,[1,2]) = 0;
>> F_pink = F; F_pink(:,:,2) = 0;
```

Here's a subplot of the result:

[image]

Furthermore, you should know that the 'naive' way of producing a grayscale image does not preserve the 'luminosity' of colours as perceived by the human eye, since 'green' at the same intensity as 'red' and 'blue' will actually be perceived as *brighter* by the human eye, and similarly 'red' is brighter than 'blue'. Matlab provides an `rgb2gray` function which converts an rgb image to a grayscale image that correctly preserves luminance. This is irrelevant for your *pure* red, green, and blue conversions, but it may be something to think about with respect to a 'pink-to-grayscale' image. For instance, compare the two images below, you will see subtle contrast differences.

```
>> F_pinktogray_naive = mean(F(:,:,[1,3]), 3);
>> F_pinktogray_luminance = rgb2gray(F_pink);
```

A subplot of the two:

[image]

In a sense, you probably care more about the left (naive) one, because you don't care about converting the pink one to a gray one "visually", but you care more about the red and blue fluorofores being "comparable" in terms of their intensity on the grayscale image instead (since they represent measurements rather than a visual scene). But it's an important distinction to keep in mind when converting rgb images to grayscale.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the bottom image is a grayscale image, just visualised with the 'hot' map, which I think results in more intuitive images than the gray colormap. Also, the images were produced with `imagesc` which means the values are scaled (i.e. lowest becomes 0 and highest becomes 1). There are ways around this if you don't care for scaling (e.g. the imshow allows you to specify such limits, as per the answers above; or you can simply replicate the grayscale channel to all r.g.b. channels, such that you have a 'gray' rgb image, hence imagesc won't scale, but it'll interpret them as rgb).